# My L3 cache size showing zero in wmic (cmd)

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, cache, wmic, cpu-cache

I purchased a desktop system which has 6 MB Cache. When I checked the L3 cache in the BIOS I didn't find a L3 cache.
I the tried to use another method in from the command line to confirm the L3 cache size.

This is the command I tried to get the L3cache value:

```
wmic cpu get L3CacheSize
```

It displays a zero result (0). But same command shows works on my other system (my Dell Inspiron 3521), it displays L3 cache of 3MB which is absolutely correct.

I don't understand what does this mean. I've never seen this before.
Could it mean I have no L3 cache?

Comment: What processor does the computer have? Could the L3 cache be disabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Dear It has 3.0 GHZ Processor.

Comment: That's not a valid processor model.

Comment: And who makes the processor? What is the **exact** model number of the processor?

Comment: okay I again see and tell u in a moment sory for my mistake.

Comment: Processor Model/Type is E8400

Comment: it Shows me 6M cache on internet, but not show L3 cache in BIOS and also not in CMD

Answer (score 5):

The [Intel E8400 processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/33910/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8400-6M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) has 6MB of L2 cache and no L3 cache.

You can use `Wmic Cpu get L2CacheSize` to see the amount of L2 cache.

If you want to know more about how cache can affect performance, you can read up about it, e.g. [Gallery of Processor Cache Effects](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/).

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on `wmic cpu`, on my system it does not show correct cache sizes. Bios should know cache sizes, but there are different kinds of bioses, some do not show cache sizes at all. I usually check such things using CPU-Z program.